# Replicate a row (specific columns) based on a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, repeat

Is there a straightforward way in dplyr to expand a dataframe by replicating a row based on a specific vector?

For example, I have following dataframe:

```
df <- tibble(Year=c(2019),
       cat1=c("A","B"),
       cat2=c("X","Y"),
       value1=c(1,2),
       value2=c(10,20))

selected_years <- c(2019:2021)
```

where I would like to replicate the row where `cat1=="A"` for the years 2019-2021. The values of some columns (value1, cat) should be taken from the original year 2019, some other columns (value2) filled with NAs.

The final output should look like:

```
Year cat   value1 value2
2019 A          1     10
2020 A          1     NA
2021 A          1     NA
2019 B          2     20
```

I tried with `bind_rows()`...however, the result is not fully what I wanted (I only get the "A"-Part not the "B"-Part), and I am not sure if this is really the most intuitive/dplyr way to go, or if another approach (or even specific function) would be more reasonable:

```
df%>%
  filter(cat1=="A",Year==2019)%>%
  bind_rows(
    data.frame(
    Year=setdiff(selected_years,.$Year),
    cat1=.$cat1,
    value1=.$value1
    )
  )
)
```

**Edit:**
I also tried using `expand` and `right_join`, but I then my desired column values are not repeated:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(df %>%
                      filter(cat1=="A",Year==2019)%>%
                      expand(Year=c(2019:2021)))
```

Maybe an approach involving `case_when`?

Answer (score 1):

The part where you only want to keep specfic values and others not, makes this tricky. It is easy to expand the vector on **all** values using `rowwise` and `unnest` together with the condition in `if_else`. In the last step we just reset the values to `NA` which we don't want to replicate. If you have more than one value that you want to set `NA`, we can use `across`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Year=c(2019),
             cat1=c("A","B"),
             cat2=c("X","Y"),
             value1=c(1,2),
             value2=c(10,20))

selected_years <- c(2019:2021)


df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(Year = if_else(cat1 == "A", list(selected_years), list(Year))) %>% 
  unnest(Year) %>% 
  mutate(value2 = if_else(Year != 2019, NA_real_, value2))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    Year cat1  cat2  value1 value2
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  2019 A     X          1     10
#> 2  2020 A     X          1     NA
#> 3  2021 A     X          1     NA
#> 4  2019 B     Y          2     20
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Or we could create a `df2` and `full_join` it with `df`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df2 <- tibble(Year = selected_years,
             cat1 = "A",
             cat2 = "X",
             value1 = 1)

df %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = c("Year", "cat1", "cat2", "value1"))

#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>    Year cat1  cat2  value1 value2
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  2019 A     X          1     10
#> 2  2019 B     Y          2     20
#> 3  2020 A     X          1     NA
#> 4  2021 A     X          1     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: What do you think about my solution is it to laborious or clumsy? direct use of `full_join` is great idea!

Comment: @TarJae: Your solution is not bad, but a bit longish due to the many `mutate` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(selected_years) %>% 
  mutate(cat1 = "A") %>% 
  full_join(df, by = "cat1") %>% 
  mutate(selected_years = ifelse(is.na(selected_years), Year, selected_years)) %>% 
  group_by(cat1) %>% 
  mutate(value2 = ifelse(row_number() != 1, NA, value2)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Year = selected_years, cat = cat1, value1, value2)
```

```
   Year cat   value1 value2
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  2019 A          1     10
2  2020 A          1     NA
3  2021 A          1     NA
4  2019 B          2     20
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on `dplyr::bind_rows`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Year=c(2019),
             cat1=c("A","B"),
             cat2=c("X","Y"),
             value1=c(1,2),
             value2=c(10,20))

selected_years <- c(2020:2021)

df %>% 
  bind_rows(data.frame(
    Year=selected_years, filter(., cat1 == "A") %>% select(-Year, -value2))) %>% 
    arrange(cat1)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>    Year cat1  cat2  value1 value2
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  2019 A     X          1     10
#> 2  2020 A     X          1     NA
#> 3  2021 A     X          1     NA
#> 4  2019 B     Y          2     20
```